# Which usage of compareTo method is more understandable?

Tags: java, compareto

I want to sort objects based on Boolean values and I want to sort true values before false values.

Which of these implementations of compareTo is more readable?

Using -1 to change default behavior

```
public class Example implements Comparable<Example>{

  Boolean isOk;

  public int compareTo(Example o) {
      return -1 * this.isOk.compareTo(o.isOk);
  }

}
```

or swap sides of Boolean#compareTo method?

```
public class ExampleTwo implements Comparable<ExampleTwo>{

  Boolean isOk;

  public int compareTo(ExampleTwo o) {
      return o.isOk.compareTo(this.isOk);
  }

}
```

Comment: Using `-1 *` introduces a subtle bug if the the `compareTo()` method ever returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, because `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. For that reason I wouldn't ever write a `compareTo()` method that could return such extreme values, but it would be absolutely conforming to the specification, so you must be able to handle it.

Comment: @Joachim: I was just writing the same thing in my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first form is simply *wrong* - because if `compareTo` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it will try to negate that - and result in `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again.

The easiest way to fix that is just to use the code from the second snippet.

On the other hand:

- Both could fail if `isOk` is null
- If you're really only using Booleans, a simple truth table may be simpler
- It's *possible* that `Boolean.compareTo` will never return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. I wouldn't rely on that though.

Comment: I agree with the answer but would like to point out #2 could also fail if o is null, and (though I agree #1 is not ideal) the Integer.MIN_VALUE issue could be fixed with a call to Math.signum.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the [`Ordering` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (formerly [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)), it implements `Comparator`, so it can be used as a drop-in replacement:

```
Ordering<Object> reverseOrdering = Ordering.natural().reverse();
```